# Finite Difference in Polar Co-ordinates

Tags: pde, finite-difference, boundary-conditions, parabolic-pde, elliptic-pde

**Background**

Please note that I am duplicating the question on scicomp. I have already asked this in math.

I am trying to come up with a scheme in Polar Co-ordinates for the following PDE:

**PDE I am trying to solve**
$$  u_t - (u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r} * u_r + \frac{1}{\theta} * u_{\theta\theta} + bu) = f(r,\theta, t)$$

I am extending the ideas from the book [1] which is already given for the PDE:

**PDE in [1]**

$$u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r} * u_r + \frac{1}{\theta} * u_{\theta\theta} = f(r,\theta, t)$$

The book discusses a particular scheme in pages 333-334 to solve the above PDE. I am listing the scheme below for convenience and its notation.

**Scheme proposed for the above PDE in [1]**

$$\frac{1}{r_i} (r_{i+1/2} \frac{u_{i+1j} - u_{ij}}{\Delta r} - r_{i-1/2}\frac{u_{ij} - u_{i-1j}}{\Delta r}) \frac{1}{\Delta r} + \frac{1}{r_i^2} \frac{u_{ij+1} - 2u_{ij} + u_{ij-1}}{\Delta \theta^2} = f_{ij}$$

where $u_{ij}$ and $f_{ij}$ are the grid functions at $(r_i, \theta_j) = (i\Delta r, j\Delta \theta)$

Further, to avoid difficulties arising at the origin because of the $\frac{1}{r}$ terms in the scheme, the book goes on to integrate the PDE over a small disc (D) of radius $\epsilon$ near the origin $r=0$, applies the Gauss-Divergence Theorem to get the following result:

$$\iint_D f \;r\;dr\;d\theta =  \iint_D (u_{rr} + \frac{1}{r} * u_r + \frac{1}{\theta} * u_{\theta\theta}) \; \;r\;dr\;d\theta = \iint_D \nabla. (\nabla u) \; \;r\;dr\;d\theta  = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \;\epsilon\;d\theta$$

These are later approximated as follows:

$$f(0) * \epsilon^2 * \pi = \sum_{j=1}^{J} \frac{u_{1j}-u_0}{\Delta r}  \epsilon\; \Delta \theta$$

From which it solves for $u_0$.

**Note**: $J\Delta \theta = 2 \pi$ and $I\Delta r = R$ where R: radius of the domain.

**Question**

i) How do I extend the idea for the terms *$u_t$*, *$bu$* terms above when computing an approximation for *$u_0$* for my PDE?

I propose to treat *$bu$* term where *$b$* is a constant the same way as *$f$* is treated in the approximation above. But it is unclear to me as to what I need to do for *$u_t$*.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Even pointers to read a particular book/topic.

Thanks!

**References**:
[1] Elliptic Partial Differential Equations and Difference Schemes
Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations, Second Edition. 2004, 311-338

Comment: For $u_t$, you will typically apply a timestepping scheme and approximate this with a forward/backwards difference or some fancier multistep scheme. This means that you'll need to use your solution at the current time to bootstrap your solution at the next time.

Comment: Please understand that cross posting the exact same question on multiple SE sites is highly discouraged.  You need to keep only one copy of the question on the most appropriate site and delete the other, or modify them to be distinct from each other.

Comment: Could you add a link to the question on MSE? It is good practice here to cross-link double posts, so that readers can see the (future) answers and the discussion on both sites.

Comment: Your questions is really just "how to discretize a time-dependent PDE in the time dimension."  Your PDE is not elliptic; look at any book that discusses discretization of parabolic PDEs.

Comment: @hardmath, I have not done Finite Elements. I am not sure that I can do it with FE at the moment.

Comment: @JLC the question was what happens to $u_t$ when $\iint_D u_t r dr d\theta$ when we try to integrate over a small disk like in the question.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I guess you are trying to say something along these lines: if I can argue saying that I can interchange the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ with $\iint_D$ then I can replace it as $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(u_0 * \epsilon^2 \pi)$ which becomes: $\pi \epsilon^2 (\frac{u_0^{i+1} - u_0^i}{\Delta t})$ if I am using forward time approximation. Is my thinking correct? And since I know the initial condition for the entire domain, I know $u_0^0$

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, the question did not garner much interest in mse. If you all agree what I've written in the comment seems like a viable solution approach, I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @Paul, Thank you! I will ensure that such cross posting does not happen again. I have deleted the question at MSE

Comment: Yes, the time-discretization scheme can be chosen as forward Euler steps, using the finite-difference scheme for polar "space" coordinates that you've otherwise adopted.  It seems to me that the small disk at the origin is (by use of the divergence theorem) a kind of Galerkin approximation, so that makes the "space" discretization a mix of finite-difference and something similar to finite-element methods.

Comment: @mod0 have you solved this issue?